# Independence implies zero mixed cumulants?

Tags: probability-theory, independence, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

**What is a proof the following claim please?**

> If $X^1$ and $X^2$ are independent (the superscripts don't denote power), then all mixed cumulants involving $X^1$ and $X^2$ alone are zero.

---

**Notation and clarification**: here, I follow the notation of [McCullagh (1987)](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~pmcc/tensorbook/). Consider a random vector $X$ whose components are $X^1,\ldots,X^p$. Define the **moments**:
$$
\kappa^i=E(X^i),\quad\kappa^{ij}=E(X^iX^j),\quad\kappa^{ijk}=E(X^iX^jX^k),\quad\ldots
$$
and the **moment generating function** (for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^p$ such that the series below converge)
$$
M_X(\xi)=1+\sum_i\xi_i\kappa^i+\sum_{i,j}\xi_i\xi_j\kappa^{ij}/2!+\sum_{i,j,k}\xi_i\xi_j\xi_k\kappa^{ijk}/3!+\cdots
$$
and the **cumulant generating function** $K_X(\xi)=\log[M_X(\xi)]$. The **cumulants** $\kappa^i$, $\kappa^{i,j}$, $\kappa^{i,j,k}$, $\ldots$ (note the commas!) are then defined via
$$
K_X(\xi)=1+\sum_i\xi_i\kappa^i+\sum_{i,j}\xi_i\xi_j\kappa^{i,j}/2!+\sum_{i,j,k}\xi_i\xi_j\xi_k\kappa^{i,j,k}/3!+\cdots
$$

> McCullagh claims that if $X^i$ and $X^j$ are independent, then
>   $$
> \kappa^{\underbrace{i,\ldots,i}_{r},\underbrace{j,\ldots,j}_{s}}=0,\quad\forall r,s\geq 1.
> $$
>   This is the claim I'm trying to understand.